# Validating ASP.NET MVC2 FormCollection against Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, validation, model-binding

Let's say I have a user class setup with validation like this:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ssUserMetaData))]
public partial class ssUser
{

}

class ssUserMetaData
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is a required field.")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Name must be 100 characters or less.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is a required field.")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Username must be 50 characters or less.")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email address is a required field.")]
    [Email(ErrorMessage = "Email address must be a valid format.")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Email address must be 100 characters or less.")]
    [DisplayName("Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is a required field.")]
    [StringLength(1000, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = "Passwords must be at least 6 characters long.")]
    [DisplayName("Password")]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have an update method that only allows users to update a couple fields, like Name and Email. I don't want to resubmit all of the data for this form to pass model binding, but I would like to use the validation rules configured here to check against a specific value in the form collection.

Something like this imaginary code...

```
bool result = ModelState.ValidateField("Email", formCollection["Email"]);
```

Is there a way do do something like this so I can avoid repeating my validation rules? Thanks!

Comment: So are you saying that you want to share the model attributes / properties over 2 forms?

Comment: If possible, I only need the update form to be a limited subset of the creation form. For example, you're not allowed to change your username, but you are allowed to change your email address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about having the small form use the NameAndEmail class and the large form use SsUserMetaData?

```
class NameAndEmail
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is a required field.")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Name must be 100 characters or less.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email address is a required field.")]
    [Email(ErrorMessage = "Email address must be a valid format.")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Email address must be 100 characters or less.")]
    [DisplayName("Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
class SsUserMetaData : NameAndEmail
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is a required field.")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Username must be 50 characters or less.")]
    public string Username { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is a required field.")]
    [StringLength(1000, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = "Passwords must be at least 6 characters long.")]
    [DisplayName("Password")]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Would I be using `public ActionResult Update(NameAndEmail user)` in this case?

Comment: And your view (or partial) can be typed to that also.

Comment: Cool, I think this is working. I kept my model on the view as `ssUser` and just made sure to run a `TryUpdateModel` first so it had the proper values. Thank you!